# Is it possible to attend an event programmatically using Facebook C# SDK?

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

Is it possible to attend an event programmatically using Facebook C# SDK providing that I have access token ?

Answer (score 5):

Yes you can,send a `GET` request to this url

`https://graph.facebook.com/EVENT_ID/{attending|maybe|declined}`

along with your access token.

---

Link to Facebook Doc: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/

Answer (score 4):

Yes right.. You need to POST the request to the URL https://graph.facebook.com/EVENT_ID/attending